# codeigniter how to populate second dropdown list based on the first one using codeigniter:

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter-3

I have tried the following but what i need just to populate two dependent drop down (penality_type based on vehicle_type) list:
Is there some one to show me how to implement here please:

This is my Controller:

```
public function index()
    {
    $data['vehicle_type'] = $this->vehicle_type_model->getAllVtype();
        $data['penality_type'] = $this->vehicle_type_model->getAllPenalityType();
         $this->load->view('admin/penality_type_price/view_penality_type_price', $data);
    }
```

This is vehicle_type_model:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class vehicle_type_model extends CI_Model {

    /*
    * Get All Vehicle types
    */

    public function getAllVtype()
    {
        $result = $this->db->get('vehicle_type');
        return $result->result_array();
    }


        public function getAllPenalityType()
    {
        $result = $this->db->get('penality_type');
        return $result->result_array();
    }

}
```

This is my View:

```
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="vehicle_type_id">Vehicle Type</label>
            <select name="vehicle_type_id" class="form-control vehicle_type_id">
                <option value="">Select Vehicle type</option>
            </select>

        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="penality_type_id">penality type</label>
            <select name="penality_type_id" class="form-control penality_type_id">
                <option value="">Select penality type</option>
            </select>  
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is incorrect. I assume that your penalty type is dependent on vehicle type, so you should pass vehicle_type id through ajax to the controller, then to your database and load them into the penalty type drop-down.

Please refer below code

Your **index** function will have just this,

```
public function index()
{
    $data['vehicle_type'] = $this->vehicle_type_model->getAllVtype();
    $this->load->view('admin/penality_type_price/view_penality_type_price', $data);
}
```

Your view

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="vehicle_type_id">Vehicle Type</label>
   <select name="vehicle_type" class="form-control vehicle_type_id" id = "vehicle_type">
       <option value="">Select Vehicle type</option>
       <?php foreach($vehicle_type as $row) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row->vehicle_type_id ?>"><?php echo $row->vehicle_type_name; ?></option>
       <?php } ?>
   </select>
</div>
```

**AJAX Code**

```
var base_url = "<?php echo base_url; ?>";
$("#vehicle_type").change(function () {
        if ($('#vehicle_type').val() != "") {
            $.ajax({
                url: base_url + "your_controller/get_penality_by_id",
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    'vehicle_type_id': $('#vehicle_type').val()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if($data){
                       $("#penality_type").html(data);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**Controller**

```
public function get_penality_by_id(){
    $vehicle_type_id = $this->input->post('vehicle_type_id');
    $data = array('vehicle_type_id' => $vehicle_type_id);
    $result = $this->your_model_name->get_penality($data);

    if($result){
       $option = "<option value=''>--Select an Option--</option>";
       foreach ($result as $row){
           $option .= "<option value='".$row->penality_id."'>".$row->penality_name."</option>";             
       }
       echo $option;
    }else{
       echo $option = "<option value=''>--Select an Option--</option>";
  }
}
```

**Model**

```
public function get_penality($data){
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('table-name');
   $this->db->where($data);
   $result_set = $this->db->get();
   if($result_set->num_rows() > 0){
      return $result_set->result();
   }
   else {
      return FALSE;
   }
}
```

Please note that your vehicle type drop-down option will have the vehicle_type id, which can be used for fetching your dependent penalty. Hope this can help you.